# Get array from string in pattern - key1:val1,val2,..;key2:val1,

Tags: php, regex

I would like to get from a string like this

```
color:blue,red;size:s
```

to an associative multiarray

```
[
    color => [blue,red],
    size => [s]
]
```

I tried with `([a-z]+):([a-z^,]+)` but it's not enough; I don't know how to recursive it or something.

Comment: Maybe try use explode(';', $data); it will give you array of pairs so you can use foreach or array walk

Comment: With a regex, it is [still no fun](https://ideone.com/HeQdPU), use the answers below.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Especially if you don't know the names of the keys.

Comment: @Mike: No, that is not a problem, the key names are extracted into Group 1.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew But what I mean is that they're still hard-coded. If we don't know the keys beforehand it makes it even less "fun"

Comment: @Mike: No, the *key* names are NOT hardcoded. I just used the same values for group names. See [this demo](https://ideone.com/uuYOLU).

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew I didn't know about group names in regex. I stand corrected.

Comment: If the string is not that simple a regex will be required, so, let it be inside a comment.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I wouldn't use regular expressions for something like this. Instead use [explode()](http://php.net/explode) several times.

```
<?php

$str = 'color:blue,red;size:s';

$values = explode(';', $str);

$arr = [];
foreach($values as $val) {
    $parts = explode(':', $val);
    $arr[$parts[0]] = explode(',', $parts[1]);
}
```

Output:

```
Array
(
    [color] => Array
        (
            [0] => blue
            [1] => red
        )

    [size] => Array
        (
            [0] => s
        )

)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$dataText   =   'color:blue,red;size:s';

$data   =   explode(';', $dataText);

$outputData =   [];

foreach ($data as $item){
    $itemData   =   explode(':', $item);
    $outputData[$itemData[0]]   =   explode(',', $itemData[1]);
}

print_r('<pre>');
print_r($outputData);
print_r('</pre>');
```

Comment: That's like an exact copy of my answer :P

Comment: Just realized :D but seriously, it's easiest way to do this.

Answer (score 0):

With regex is not so simple like explode, but you can try this...

```
$re = '/(\w+)\:([^;]+)/';
$str = 'color:blue,red;size:s'; 
preg_match_all($re, $str, $matches);
// Print the entire match result 
$result = array();
$keys = array();
for($i = 1; $i < count($matches); $i++) {
    foreach($matches[$i] as $k => $val){
        if($i == 1) {
            $result[$val] = array();
            $keys[$k] = $val;
        } else {
            $result[$keys[$k]] = $val;
        }
    }
}
echo '<pre>';
print_r($result);
echo '</pre>';
```

result

```
Array
(
    [color] => blue,red
    [size] => s
)
```

Comment: From what I gather, the values should be arrays. So `blue,red` should actually be `[blue,red]`. I'm not sure if that can even be done without an `explode` somewhere along the line.

Comment: Sorry... I don't understand. I have not found a way to create 'sub-groups' in regex. Maybe another regex just to the value?

Comment: I'm not that proficient at regex either, so I don't know whether matching sub-groups like that is possible.